# Elasticsearch: can this complex filtere query be simplified?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following filtered query:

```
{
  "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query": { 
                ....
            },
            "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "should" : [
                        {
                            bool : {
                                "must" : [
                                    { "term1" : { "name1" : "value1" } },
                                    { "term2" : { "name2" : "value2" } }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool" : {
                                "must" : [
                                    ......
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool" : {
                                "must" : [ 
                                    ......
                                ]
                            }
                        },  
                        {
                            "bool" : {
                                "must" : [
                                    .......
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Is there any room for me to improve the complex filters without harming performance? How?

I feel the filter part can be simplified, but not sure. Also not sure about any performance impact.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Under each must clause, there is a GROUP of clauses. See the first must clause for an example.

**UPDATE 2**

According to Duc's input and Mario's updated answer, I am very happy that what I have so far is the right way. No changes are is needed.

*I choose Mario's response as the answer because it confirms that mine is right.*

Comment: If the conditions between `must` clauses are independence and cannot be merged then I think this is the simplest form

Comment: Duc, thanks for your input!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need [Bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with only one must clause. You put your conditions directly within the outer `should`.

```
{
  "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query": { 
                ....
            },
            "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "should" : [
                        {
                                    .......
                        },
                        {
                                    .......
                        },
                        {
                                    .......
                        },  
                        {
                                    .......
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

**UPDATE:** since I see from your update that you have several clauses within your nested `must` statements, my suggestion is no longer valid. Your query filter is ok like it is (except that `term1` and `term2` aren't valid, but that's not the point of the question)

Comment: Mario, thanks so much for helping me out!!! Could you please provide an example for one { .... }. I am not sure about what is there. Also, any performance impact with your way? Best.

Comment: it will be the same as what you have in your must clause, for example term : { name : "abc" }

Comment: Hi Ryan, in my case, under each must clause, there is a GROUP (NOT one) of term filters. It seems the suggested approach is going to change the semantics of the original query. Am I right? I updated my original post.

Comment: Mario, thanks for your follow-up! Best. I selected your post as the answer because it shows the solution another way.